# Facebook API Accuracy

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I have a quick question for the Facebook Guru's here.

A couple of years back I have written a facebook app that retrieves the amount of likes assigned to a photo. At the time, I was surprised to find out that neither FQL nor the Graph API returned accurate like counts at the time.

Now, I have been asked to develop a photo contest where people can vote on a few photo's to pick a winner. This contest is supposed to run on a Facebook page, as a facebook app and I'm trying to evaluate if I can use facebook's likes as voting mechanism.

I figure since Facebook's API changes rather often, maybe they have resolved the accuracy problems by now. I tried digging around in facebook's developer documentation, but I could not find if any of the current Facebook API's return accurate like counts on user submitted photo's.

Does anyone know if FQL or Graph API are currently able to provide accurate like counts for user-submitted photos?

Answer (score 0):

I can't attest to accuracy but a Photo's 'likes' connection can be queried generating alist of likes as per the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/). See example call below.

https://graph.facebook.com/10151509108346729/likes?access_token={any_valid_access_token}

Comment: Thanx for the info. I am experiencing no problems loading a list of likes. My question is specifically about the accuracy of the results.

Comment: I doubt there's any documentation of error margins for Facebook queries. I think your best bet would be to try some experiments (i.e. do the API query and then check that against a visual inspection of the UI.